# Postgresql SQL exclude query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm relatively new to Postgresql and SQL in general. I've been sitting on this problem for some time and can't figure out how to write the query to get the result I want.

I have this example table

| User | Name | Paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | aaa | true |
| B | bbb | true |
| C | ccc | false |
| D | aaa | false |
| E | eee | false |

If I execute the query `select * from table where Paid is false` then I will get

| User | Name | Paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | ccc | false |
| D | aaa | false |
| E | eee | false |

From this table, I want to exlude all users who have the same `Name` as users in the `Paid=true` set. So in the end I want to have this result

| User | Name | Paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | ccc | false |
| E | eee | false |

SO basically I want to get all users who have not paid `Paid = false` and on top of that, exclude all users with the same names as the users who have paid `Paid = true`.

How do I do this in one query? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use not exists as below:

**Schema:**

```
 CREATE TABLE tableUser ("User" varchar(10), Name varchar(10), Paid boolean);
     
 INSERT INTO tableUser  VALUES('A', 'aaa', 'true');
 INSERT INTO tableUser  VALUES('B', 'bbb', 'true');
 INSERT INTO tableUser  VALUES('C', 'ccc', 'false');
 INSERT INTO tableUser  VALUES('D', 'aaa', 'false');
 INSERT INTO tableUser  VALUES('E', 'eee', 'false');
```

**Query:**

```
 select User, Name, Paid from tableuser t
 where paid is false and
       not exists (select 1
                   from tableuser tb
                   where t.name = tb.name and tb.paid is true );
```

**Output:**

| user | name | paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| u_519553787 | ccc | f |
| u_519553787 | eee | f |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=248a8c62335c656aebd8761aa93b7612)*

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not paid and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.paid
                 );
```

Of course, the `not paid` in the outer query is redundant.  So, you can just use:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.paid
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7a76d4f20b382304daf5f4f737efe2c9)

You can exclude the names with a `WHERE` subquery:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM mytable
WHERE "Name" NOT IN (                               -- 2
    SELECT "Name" FROM mytable WHERE "Paid" = true  -- 1
)
```

1. Get all names of paid records
2. Take them and filter all related records